# How to stop two phones that are synced together

Tags: data-synchronization

My and my daughters phones are synced together. We're sharing the same storage. My phone continually tells me that I don't have enough storage space. How do I remove my daughters contents off my phone and quit receiving her stuff from her phone?

Comment: Don't both use the same Apple ID. Get one each & set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an iCloud account to your daughter then link her phone to that new account from Settings -> iCloud.

Then you can manage your iCloud storage from settings -> General -> Use -> iCloud -> Manage Storage and you will find everything fill your iCloud account and you can remove what you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue to use the sam Apple ID, go to Settings -> iTunes and App Store. you will see a list of 4 items under "Automatic Downloads". Uncheck all the content you do not want to sync to your device. But, you have to manually remove all of her content from your phone that was downloaded prior to this.